# How to display empty dropdown in view page

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have my get and post methods . I populate my data during post methods based on some value. When i try to run the program it gives me a here is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable' that has the key  because there is no data in the dropdown. How can i show empty dropdown and bind the same during post method .

Comment: what did you tried? the normal procedure will create an empty dropdown... the dropdown will always be created, just not populated with data, or you can simply use the normal html `<select id="youAttributeName" name="youAttributeName"></select>`

Comment: I want it to be bound in post method , if i use normal html , how i can bind it in post method

Comment: just use `name` as your property... if you have a model like `MyViewModel.Cars` that is a collection, your select should have a `name="Cars"`

Comment: If you have not figure it out yet, share your view & get/post code.

Comment: I jus wrote a false query .. it displays empty now

Comment: You can use `Enumerable.Empty<T>` to generate your `SelectList`

Answer (score 0):

The `DropDownListFor` template must be provided with an IEnumerable to work properly. If you want an empty list, the best way to provide an empty IEnumerable is to use the [`Enumerable.Empty<>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb341042%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) static method.

Your code would then look like this:

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Name, Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>(), "-- Select Name --", new { @class = "form-control" })
```